# Reduce EPS file generated by Apache FOP

Tags: apache, reduce, apache-fop, eps, exceed

Fo far I have generated EPS files using the inkscape and these files were compact 2-3Kb [1]

For several important reasons now files are generated by Apache FOP. Adobe Illustrator shows the old and new versions of the same files in the same way and that is good. But the files from Apache FOP have become 12-15Kb [2]. The size of files is important to me

Inside the old file [1] there are a few headers and commands like lineto, moveto.
Inside the new file [2] there are a lot of text, and some fragments of the text are the same at the beginning, in the middle and at the end of the file.

Do EPS need this repeated information?

How can I get rid of redundant data?

- [1] file from inkspace  https://www.dropbox.com/s/mokxyl8ttjdfgti/inkscape_amex%5B1%5D.eps
- [2] file from Apache FOP https://www.dropbox.com/s/l19fedlxnjxnhk7/apache_fop_amex%5B2%5D.eps

Comment: Details:  

I use Apache FOP to generate PS files from SVG and then convert them into EPS using ps2eps utility  

    `$ java -jar fop.jar -imagein amex.svg -ps amex.ps`  

[3] original sample SVG https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtt3aakjqdlgwi3/amex.svg  

[4] PS file from Apache FOP https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz1wvkslpdzuzbh/amex.ps  

    `$ ps2eps amex.ps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/eps2eps1.html Ghostscript PostScript "distiller"

`$ eps2eps amex.eps amex.optimized.eps`